# Python: transform a list to a list of the list, by duplicating the values

Tags: python, list

maybe a simple question, but I would like to transform a list to a list of the list, by duplicating the values. What is the most efficient way to do it?  Many thanks!

The following

```
data = ['a','b','c']
```

should look like:

```
data = [
    ['a','a','a'], 
    ['b','b','b'], 
    ['c','c','c'], 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`List Comprehensions`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/):

```
data = ['a','b','c']
rep = 3
out = [[d]*rep for d in data]
print(out)
```

---

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]
```